# Ruby: count Post quantity per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have: `scaffold post title:string body:text`

How can I display post quantity created per day (based on `created_at:datetime`)?

I figure out it will contain something like

`= Post.count(:id)`#daily...

How can I show it in a table like this?

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Date
      %th Post quantity
  %tbody
    - @posts.each do |post|
      %tr
        %td= post.date
        %td= post.quantity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a hash of dates to count

```
Post.group("DATE(created_at)").count
```

To display in your table

```
- Post.group("DATE(created_at)").count.each do |date, post_count|
  %tr
    %td= date
    %td= post_count
```

Comment: Looks cool, but it looks like I'm too weak to make use of it yet... Could you please check out the updated question :-)

Comment: Also, should be noted: in some RDBMS, you can create an index on calculated values such as `DATE(created_at)`.

Comment: Nice, I did not know that `count` on a `group` behaved like that.

Comment: Works great. Thank you, T J !

Answer (score 0):

For posts that were created today:

```
Post.where("DATE(`value_date`) = CURDATE()").count
```

While I think that answer given by @t-j is more generic, the above is more lightweight and is executed times faster.